# Django - Login with email or username not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my project, I implement a login system where a user can login using their username **or** their email. I basically try to find whether a users email is inserted into the form field "usernameOrEmail" or whether it is their username entered in the "usernameOrEmail" field. I then log them in if a user is found.

Here is my code:

```
def login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        isFound = ""
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data.get("usernameOrEmail"))
                isFound = "usernameFound"
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(email=form.cleaned_data.get("usernameOrEmail"))
                    isFound = "emailFound"
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    isFound = "nothingFound"




            if isFound == "usernameFound":
                print("USERNAME FOUND!")
                user = auth.authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data.get("usernameOrEmail"), password=form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    context["error"] = "Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid"
            elif isFound == "emailFound":
                print("EMAIL FOUND")
                user = auth.authenticate(email=form.cleaned_data.get("usernameOrEmail"), password=form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
                if user is not None:
                    print("YES")
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    print("NO")
                    context["error"] = "Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid"
            else:
                context["error"] = "Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid"
        else:
            context["error"] = "Please enter valid form data"
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
```

Weirdly, the terminal return the print statement "EMAIL FOUND" meaning that the email of a user was found, however the "NO" print statement is also printed, and the message "Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid" is returned in the template.

The other weird thing is that this system works for the users username, meaning when I enter a users username into the "usernameOrEmail" field, and I enter the correct password, the user is logged in. Anybody know the issue? thank you.

Comment: The standard authentication backend only works with a `username` and `password`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So you cannot implement username or email functionality anyway at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard authentication backend only works with a `username` and `password`. Indeed, the [`authenticate` method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L36-L49) of the `ModelBackend` is implemented as:

> ```
>     def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
>         if username is None:
>             username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
>         if username is None or password is None:
>             return
>         try:
>             user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
>         except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
>             # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
>             # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
>             UserModel().set_password(password)
>         else:
>             if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
>                 return user
> ```

This is however not a problem. You can just implement this with:

```
def login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['usernameOrEmail'])
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(email=form.cleaned_data['usernameOrEmail'])
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    user = None
            if user is not None:
                user = auth.authenticate(username=user.username, password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                context['error'] = 'Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid'
        else:
            context['error'] = 'Please enter valid form data'
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    # …
```

Comment: This has worked! Thank you. I understand most of it, however I don't understand this part:      **if user is not None:
                user = auth.authenticate(username=user.username, password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                context['error'] = 'Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid'**

Comment: Why perform  **if user is not None** twice?And why do we not perform **auth.authenticate** for the email field and we do for the username field? How are users able to login with their email if we do not perform **auth.authenticate** for the email field?

Comment: @PythonNinja007: because as specified in the answer, the authentication does not *work* on the email field.

Comment: so how can users enter their email and password, and get logged in? Which part of the code makes this work?

Comment: @PythonNinja007: we retrieve the user for that email, and then obtain the corresponding `username` of that user (the `username=user.username` part).

Comment: Ah Ok. One thing I still do not understand is the use of **if user is not none** twice. Why use it twice? Why not use it once? What does these do?

Comment: @PythonNinja007: the first one checks if we found a user, and if so we authenticate. The second checks if that authentication was succesful.

Comment: Ah right. Why couldn't we just wrap all that logic into one statment, why use two though?

Comment: @PythonNinja007: because after the first check we set the user to the result of `authenticate`. At both stages it could fail. If Python was a pure functional language, we could have wrapped it in a `Maybe` monad, but unfortunately Python does not really has syntax in place for monads.